# Spring JPA Hibernate Advantages and Tutorial

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

What are the advantages of using Spring JPA with Hibernate?

Are there any tutorials that I can look to understand the concepts and configuration? I am unable to find any good tutorials which are descriptive and explanatory...

Answer (score 2):

The main benefit is that you are using standard technologies and they integrate quite well.

[Spring in action](http://www.manning.com/walls4/) gives you some sort of tutorial, however its a book.

You should check why each of the technologies make sense for you. They all provide great benefits however each of them requires some learning.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that JPA is standart technology and many programmers around the world use it (yeah, Hibernate is wide spreaded too). You can easily change JPA provider if you need, your app can be asily redeployed to another container (not very valuable, if you use Spring, as it alreay provides you with such feature).

I think [standart guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa) is good enough. But it may be not very simple for start with it.